# I am trying to delete data from table by using forign key in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to delete data by using a foreign key but unfortunately not deleting from FreeDownloadFiles tables how can I delete data from this table please help me thanks.

Note: data is  successfully deleting from  freedownload table but not deleting from FreeDownloadFiles tables

```
free_download table
 
id  |  name | images


free_download_files table

 id | free_download_id | images
```

**Controller**

```
    public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        $freedownload = FreeDownload::findOrFail($request->deleteId);
        $freedownloadfiles = FreeDownloadFiles::where('free_download_id', $request->deleteId)->get();

        foreach ($freedownloadfiles as $key => $value) {

            $delete = $value->delete();
        }

        // apply your conditional check here
        if (false) {
            $response['error'] = 'This FreeDownload has something assigned to it.';
            return response()->json($response, 409);
        } else {
            Storage::disk('yourstitchart')->delete($freedownload->icon);
            $response = $freedownload->delete();
            return response()->json($response, 200);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a relation between the 2 models?

Comment: No need the loop, do that with one line code `FreeDownloadFiles::where('free_download_id', $request->deleteId)->delete();`

Comment: yes I have a model relationship

Comment: data is successfully deleting from db but can you please tell me how can i  delete images from the storage?

Comment: @zubairmalik you can do that like this way `Storage::delete('file.jpg');` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#deleting-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can automate the deleting of the images/files associated with the `FreeDownloadFiles` records by hooking into the model `deleting` event in the `FreeDownloadFiles` model definition.

```php
class FreeDownloadFile extends Model
{
     protected static function booted()
     {
        static::deleting(function ($record) {

            /**
             * if images field contains string with comma separated paths to image files
             * convert to array explode(',', $record->images)
             * replace comma with whatever separator is used eg ;
             */
            foreach(explode(',', $record->images) as $image) { 
                Storage::delete($image);
            }                
        });
     }
}
```

Similarly to automate deleting of `FreeDownloadFiles` associated with a `FreeDownload` we can hook into the `deleting` event for `FreeDownload`

```php
class FreeDownload extends Model
{
   protected static function booted()
     {
        static::deleting(function ($record) {

            //can also use higher order magic
            //$record->freeDownloadFiles->each->delete();

            foreach($record->freeDownloadFiles as $file) {
                $file->delete();
            }           
        });
     }
}
```

Then the controller method can become simple as

```php
public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        $freedownload = FreeDownload::findOrFail($request->deleteId);
        

        // apply your conditional check here
        if (false) {
            $response['error'] = 'This FreeDownload has something assigned to it.';
            return response()->json($response, 409);
        } else {
            Storage::disk('yourstitchart')->delete($freedownload->icon);
            $response = $freedownload->delete();
            return response()->json($response, 200);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Donkarnash thanks for helping but unfortunately I am getting an error on the FreeDownloadFile model please check the error in this link thanks. https://imageupload.io/GdlGt6PZXa.i

Comment: What is stored in the `images` column for `FreeDownloadFiles` record? What's the column type?

Comment: multi images storing in images column for FreeDownloadFiles record and column type is text

Comment: Is it comma separated paths to image files as text? Can you please post the result of `dd($freeDownloadFile->images)`;

Comment: If the `$freeDownloadFiles->images` contain comma separated string like 'path/to/image1, path/to/image2, path/to/image3' then it needs to be converted to array before being fed to foreach loop

Comment: @zubairmalik Have updated the answer to convert comma separated list of multiple paths to images for consumption in foreach loop using `explode(',', $record->images)`. Have a look and let me know. Also pls post output of `dd($freeDownloadFile->images)` if it doesn't work.